# How to describe the relationship between elements of tuple in array of tuples via types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-programming, typescript-generics

I want to describe the relationship between elements of tuple in array of tuples via types in TypeScript.

Is this possible?

```
declare const str: string;
declare const num: number;
function acceptString(str: string) { }
function acceptNumber(num: number) { }

const arr /*: ??? */ = [
    [str, acceptString],
    [num, acceptNumber],
    [str, acceptNumber], // should be error
];

for (const pair of arr) {
    const [arg, func] = pair;
    func(arg); // should be no error
}
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20enable%20all%20strict%20flags%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20str%3A%20string%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20num%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Afunction%20acceptString(str%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20acceptNumber(num%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%2F*%3A%20%3F%3F%3F%20*%2F%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bstr%2C%20acceptString%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bnum%2C%20acceptNumber%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bstr%2C%20acceptNumber%5D%2C%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20error%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(const%20pair%20of%20arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%5Barg%2C%20func%5D%20%3D%20pair%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20func(arg)%3B%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20no%20error%0D%0A%7D)

Real-world example: [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Type%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Value1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Value2%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Store1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Store2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Form1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(store%3A%20Store1)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Form2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(store%3A%20Store2)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20map%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BType.Value1%5D%3A%20%5BStore1%2C%20Form1%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BType.Value2%5D%3A%20%5BStore2%2C%20Form2%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createForm(type%3A%20Type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%5BStore%2C%20Form%5D%20%3D%20map%5Btype%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Form(new%20Store())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: Not possible to get this to fully type check. You can get an error on `[str, acceptNumber]` (requires a function and a conditional type) but the `for` is still going to require a type assertion

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you. Is this a fundamental limitation of TypeScript or this can be fixed in the future?

Comment: What do you plan do do with such an array, other than to take each element of the array and call its second element with the first element as a parameter?

Comment: TS would need to track that `arg` comes from `pair` so `func(arg)` is safe, while something like `func("")` is not. While it might be possible to track this I don't think we will see this in the near future.

Comment: @jcalz nothing in this example. But the real-world example is a bit more complicated (i added the link to the question). I think these two examples are equivalent.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir for curiosity's sake, does this requires some fundamental feature like higher-kinded types, dependent types, etc.?

Comment: @jcalz has created an issue very similar to this but for objects I believe, he can speak more to this.

Comment: Yeah I'm writing up an answer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically asking for something I've been calling [correlated record types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), for which there is currently no direct support in TypeScript.  Even in the case where you can convince the compiler to catch errors in creating such records, it is not really equipped to verify type safety when using one.

One way to implement such types would be with [existentially quantified generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) which TypeScript [does not currently support directly](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  If it did, you'd be able to describe your array as something like:

```
type MyRecord<T> = [T, (arg: T)=>void];
type SomeMyRecord = <exists T> MyRecord<T>; // this is not valid syntax
type ArrayOfMyRecords = Array<SomeMyRecord>;
```

The next best thing might be to allow `ArrayOfMyRecords` to itself be a generic type in which each element of the array is strongly typed with its analogous `T` value, and a helper function to infer the stronger type:

```
type MyRecord<T> = [T, (arg: T) => void];

const asMyRecordArray = <A extends any[]>(
  a: { [I in keyof A]: MyRecord<A[I]> } | []
) => a as { [I in keyof A]: MyRecord<A[I]> };
```

This uses [infererence from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) and [mapped tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Let's see it in action:

```
const arr = asMyRecordArray([
  [str, acceptString],
  [num, acceptNumber],
  [str, acceptNumber] // error
]);
// inferred type of arr:
// const arr:  [
//   [string, (arg: string) => void], 
//   [number, (arg: number) => void], 
//   [string, (arg: string) => void]
// ]
```

Let's fix that:

```
const arr = asMyRecordArray([
  [str, acceptString],
  [num, acceptNumber],
  [str, acceptString] 
]);
// inferred type of arr:
// const arr:  [
//   [string, (arg: string) => void], 
//   [number, (arg: number) => void], 
//   [string, (arg: string) => void]
// ]
```

So that works well enough to define `arr`.  But now look what happens when you iterate over it:

```
// TS3.3+ behavior
for (const pair of arr) {
  const [arg, func] = pair; 
  func(arg); // still error!
}
```

This is where the lack of support for correlated records burns you.  In TypeScript 3.3, support was added for calling [unions of function types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011), but that support does not touch this issue, which is: the compiler treats `func` as a *union* of functions which is completely *uncorrelated* with the type of `arg`.  When you call it, the compiler decides that it can only safely accept arguments of type `string & number`, which `arg` is not (nor is any actual value, since `string & number` collapses to `never`).

So if you go this way you'll find you need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to calm the compiler down:

```
for (const pair of arr) {
    const [arg, func] = pair as MyRecord<string | number>;
    func(arg); // no error now
    func(12345); // no error here either, so not safe
}
```

One might decide this is the best you can do and to leave it there.

---

Now, there is a way to encode existential types in TypeScript, but it involves a `Promise`-like inversion of control.  Before we go down that route, though, ask yourself: what are you going to actually *do* with a `MyRecord<T>` when you don't know `T` ?  The only reasonable thing you can do is to call its first element with its second element.  And if so, you can give a more concrete method that just *does that* without keeping track of `T`:

```
type MyRecord<T> = [T, (arg: T) => void];
type MyUsefulRecord<T> = MyRecord<T> & { callFuncWithArg(): void };

function makeUseful<T>(arg: MyRecord<T>): MyUsefulRecord<T> {
    return Object.assign(arg, { callFuncWithArg: () => arg[1](arg[0]) });
}

const asMyUsefulRecordArray = <A extends any[]>(
    a: { [I in keyof A]: MyUsefulRecord<A[I]> } | []
) => a as { [I in keyof A]: MyUsefulRecord<A[I]> };

const arr = asMyUsefulRecordArray([
    makeUseful([str, acceptString]),
    makeUseful([num, acceptNumber]),
    makeUseful([str, acceptString])
]);

for (const pair of arr) {
    pair.callFuncWithArg(); // okay!
}
```

Your real-world example could be modified similarly:

```
function creatify<T, U>(arg: [new () => T, new (x: T) => U]) {
    return Object.assign(arg, { create: () => new arg[1](new arg[0]()) });
}

const map = {
    [Type.Value1]: creatify([Store1, Form1]),
    [Type.Value2]: creatify([Store2, Form2])
};

function createForm(type: Type) {
    return map[type].create();
}
```

Emulating existential types in TypeScript is similar to the above except that it allows you to do absolutely anything to a `MyRecord<T>` that can be done if you don't know `T`.  Since in most cases this is a small set of operations, it's often easier to just support those directly instead.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: can you please explain why it is not working when MyRecord is for example `[T, T]` or `[T, { value: T }]` of `[T, () => T]`?

Comment: I can't easily deal with followup questions in the comments section of answers to questions from several years ago.  If you need help, maybe you want to post a new question with a [mre] of the issue you're facing, and then the community could take a look at it. Good luck!