# How to set a tuple in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following annotation, I receive an error when defining a tuple in typescript 3.5.3 version.
What could be the problem?

```
type Test = [string, number];
const xxx: Test = () => ['hello', 10];
```

I get error:
`Type '() => (string | number)[]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.`

Comment: Why do you have a `() => ` in there? That's lambda syntax. You're trying to assign a function to a variable with a Tuple type.

Comment: I want have a function which return some data as the tuple.... is it possible?

Comment: But you said that `Test` is a Tuple, not a function that returns a Tuple, and you have `xxx` as type `Test`. Do you want `xxx` to be a function returning a Tuple or a Tuple?

Comment: yes please in what way

Comment: Again, do you want Test to be a Type that's a function returning a Tuple, or a Tuple? Which one?

Comment: sorry I want Test to be a Type which return a Tuple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to describe the relationship between elements of tuple in array of tuples via types in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188216/how-to-describe-the-relationship-between-elements-of-tuple-in-array-of-tuples-vi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set `xxx` to type `Test`, then do something like this:

```
type Test = [string, number];

const xxx: Test = ['hello', 10];
```

OR

```
const xxx: Test = getTest();
getTest(): Test { return ['hello', 10]; }
```

**UPDATE**

Setting your `xxx` to a function that returns `Test` would look more like this:

```
type Test = () => [string, number];

const test: Test = () => ['hello', 10];
```

OR

If you want `Test` to be just the tuple, but `xxx` to be the function that returns the tuple, you could do something like this too:

```
type Test = [string, number];

const xxx: () => Test = getTest;

getTest(): Test { return ['hello', 10]; }
```

Comment: It sounds like OP actually wants `type Test = () => [string, number]`